# Cocoa How to display Informative Message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++, nsalert

I need to display informative message box in Cocoa Application, which control should i use, 
i read the document of NSAlert, but it seems, it will create the modal message box, where i need something, where i will just show a popup for fraction of seconds and will get destroyed after some time by it self.

Comment: You need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish. If the alert isn't modal, that it can't be that important and should probably be presented in another way.

Comment: Yes, it need not be a modal, but has to be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `NSTimer` for auto dismiss.

```
[self showMyMessage];//put your code in showMyMessage method to show your alert,
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self
selector:@selector(callToDismissAlert:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

After 60.0 second , iOS will call the below function

```
-(void) callToDismissAlert:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    [self dismissMyAlert];// put your code in dismissMyAlert method to dismiss your alert,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i had done the same, but i am wondering, this is not a very specific scenario and why this function is not there in the Cocoa Framework.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [Growl](http://growl.info/).

[image: Screenshot of Growl showing a “contact came online” notification: “Andrew Harvey came online”.]

It's a third-party software product, for which we provide a framework you can include in your application. See also [the application-developer page](http://growl.info/developer/).